# SQL Server query column containing list of id's

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, cfml, lucee

I am probably over complicating this, but I'm trying to do a query that returns records where one or more id's in a list (ridlist) are present in a column that is also a list of id's (rids).

There is probably a much simpler way to do this but I'm new to it and can't get my head around it.

Pseudoish query:

```
select boid, rids, address, city, state, zip
from branchoffices
where rids contains one or more of the ids in ridlist
```

I have branch offices that are responsible for different regions and I need to be able to list out all the branch offices that handle activities in a user selected list of regions.

For example:

```
branchoffice1's rid field in the db contains 1,13,22
branchoffice2's rid field contains 2,3,4
```

If the user selects regions 1 and 2, creating a list 2,3. I'd want the query to return only branchoffice2's boid. So i don't think using like % would work.

Tables:

- `regions` - rid(ident), regionname, some other columns
- `branchoffices` - boid(ident), rids, city, state, zip, some other columns

Example data:

Regions table (rid, regionname):

```
"1", "Dallas/Fort Worth"
"2", "Greater Houston"
"3", "Austin"
"4", "San Antonio"
"5", "San Marcos"
etc
```

Branchoffices table (boid, rids, city, state, phone):

```
"1", "2,3", "Houston", "TX", "1231231234"
"2", "1", "Fort Worth", "TX", "4561231234"
"3", "4,5", "San Antonio", "TX", "7891231234"
```

So in the above example data, boid 1 (Houston office) is responsible for the Greater Houston and Austin regions.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Thank you very much for any help and I apologize if I missed this being covered already.

Comment: Don't store comma separated data in your database tables.  I could give you a query, but that would almost be doing you a disservice, because the best thing for you to do is to fix your table design.  Store each `rid` in a separate row.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the response.  i'm probably not understanding properly. i have a regions table with all the rids in their own row.
then a branchoffice table with the details about each branch office, boid (identity) and that rids field (list of ids which is bad apparently lol)

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please **edit** your question and show us actual sample table data, in tabular form, formatted as code, with 4 or more leading spaces on each line.

Comment: Also... I've added the SQL Server tag for you. Please also add the tag for the sql server version you are using

Comment: my apologies this is my 1st question, i'm still learning the interface.  thanks for the patience.

Comment: thank you nick, i see how that works now 8-)

Comment: there is some sample data in there now, hopefully i did that right

Comment: You would benefit from reading about data normalization, specifically the [first normal form (1NF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). The link does a nice job of explaining why it isn't a good idea to put multiple comma-separated `rids` in a single field, and a couple of ways to set up the tables properly.

Comment: Thank you all so much! I'll read that link BobRodes, thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a separate table with one row per branch and per rid.  Why is storing ids in a string wrong?  Here are some reasons:

- The `rid` is an integer.  It should be stored as an integer, not a string.
- A column (at least using the basic column types) should store only one value.
- Foreign keys should be properly declared, and you cannot do that when the values are the wrong type.
- SQL Server has lousy string functions (just admit it).
- SQL Server cannot optimize the queries very well.
- SQL has this great way of storing lists.  It is called a *table*, not a *string*.

Sometimes, you are stuck with other people's really, really, realy bad designs.  SQL Server has a function that can help you, `split_string()`.  You can use it with a lateral join:

```
select bo.*
from branchoffices bo cross apply
     (select ss.rid
      from split_string(bo.rids) ss(rid)
      where ss.rid in (1, 2, 3)
     ) ss;
```

Note that you can also use `split_string()` on the use input:

```
with rids as (
      select rid
      from split_string('1,2,3') ss(rid)
     )
select bo.*
from branchoffices bo cross apply
     (select ss.rid
      from split_string(bo.rids) ss(rid) join
           rids
           on ss.rid = rids.rid
     ) ss;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! when i gave up last night the minute i sat down in bed i thought to myself.  I wonder if it would be ok to just create another table with those id relationships.  Thanks again!!